# Automatic change layout of a view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, layout, uiview

Is there a way to automatically have an element (eg WebView) resize when a nearby element (UIImageView) is hidden?

I have a normal UIView with a WebView in it showing HTML, but in some cases there is a need for an image above that. So I put the image above the WebView, but would like the webview to also take the space of the ImageView when this one is not present, otherwise there is a white bar.

Another option is to place it over the Webview, but I don't think there is anyway to have the text flow around the image.

Anybody any suggestions for a tidy solutions?
Thanks a million in advance!

Answer (score 2):

A handy trick I learned is to rely on `CGRectDivide()`--of course you will have to write your own `layoutSubviews` method, but it's not too difficult:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGRect bounds = self.bounds ;
    if ( !self.imageView.hidden )
    {
        CGRect slice ;
        CGRectDivide( bounds, & slice, & bounds, IMAGE_VIEW_HEIGHT, CGRectMinYEdge ) ;
        self.imageView.frame = slice ;
    }

    // bounds here contains the remaining layout space with or without the image view
    self.webView.frame = bounds ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is it such a problem to just resize your WebView in the same method that shows or hides the image?

By the way, Cocoa Autolayout was introduced for OSX Lion. iOS 6 is under NDA at the moment, but if you have a developer account, go have a look, maybe there is something like it there.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [CSLinearLayoutView](https://github.com/scalessec/CSLinearLayoutView). It tries to mimick Android's LinearLayout and RelativeLayout, and should be able to simplify dynamic resizing/moving of views.